# Jest how to test asynchronous load script

Tags: jestjs

I have a tool for asynchronously loading scripts, using jest for asynchronous testing, but jest has timed out and can't respond to scripts. How do I implement this feature?

I tried to write a test sample according to the promise of the document

This is my script loader code and Jest test code

```js
function mapLoader(key, version, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (AMap) {
      return resolve(AMap);
    }

    if (!url && (!key || !version)) {
      warn('The parameter is incorrect and must contain the url attribute or the key and version attributes.');
    }

    const aMapUrl = url || `${defaultPath}?v=${version}&key=${key}`;

    const jsApi = document.createElement('script');
    jsApi.charset = 'utf-8';
    jsApi.src = aMapUrl;
    jsApi.onerror = reject;
    jsApi.onload = () => {
      if (window.AMap) {
        AMap = window.AMap;
        // 如果不加上 setTimeout 在本地开发时，会有一定几率导致刷新页面覆盖物无法显示在地图上。
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(AMap);
        }, 0);
      } else {
        warn('AMap SDK Load Failure.');
      }
    };

    document.head.appendChild(jsApi);
  });
}
```

```js
test('test mapLoader function', () => {
  return mapLoader('d2d76e2274bf5973ecfb1f68454b6f3b', '1.4.15').then(AMap => {
    expect(AMap).toBe('peanut butter');
  });
});
```

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

Comment: There is a missing piece of code in the above case.


```js
const defaultPath = 'https://webapi.amap.com/maps'
```

Comment: Read more about testing asynchronous code here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: This is not related to asynchronous, but the load script does not respond to the load event. There are also no examples of related scripting operations in the jest DOM operation.

Comment: @陶旭生 Were you able to find a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @dracodormiens This is caused by jsdom, unless it fixes the problem, I use Karma + Mocha + Chai instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to test like this:

```
test('test mapLoader function', (done) => {
  return mapLoader('d2d76e2274bf5973ecfb1f68454b6f3b', '1.4.15')
    .then(AMap => {
      expect(AMap).toBe('peanut butter');
      done();
    });
});
```

Or even let Jest wait and not executing other tests until this finishes with the `async` keyword:

```
test('test mapLoader function', async (done) => {
  return mapLoader('d2d76e2274bf5973ecfb1f68454b6f3b', '1.4.15')
    .then(AMap => {
      expect(AMap).toBe('peanut butter');
      done();
    });
});
```

If you want to tell Jest, the test should fail, in these cases, you'd call `done(error)`.